# OpenCV: threshold operation with unexpected result

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv, threshold

I read a white picture using OpenCV:

[image]

I apply this threshold over it:

```
import cv2    
# Read image
src = cv2.imread("threshold.png", cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)    
# Set threshold and maxValue
thresh = 0
maxValue = 255    
# Basic threshold example
th, dst = cv2.threshold(src, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY);
# Find Contours  
contours, hierarchy=cv2.findContours(dst,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Draw Contour
cv2.drawContours(dst,countours,-1,(255,255,255),3)
cv2.imshow("Contour",dst)
```

So according the `cv2.THRESH_BINRARY` thresholding type, I logically expect a totally white picture. Why ? because I set `thresh=0` and `maxValue=255`, so the result I expect is logic according to the official documentation that says in this case:

[image]

But I get a totally black picture as a result (pixels of `dst` set to `0` even if they are greater than `thresh` in `src` picture)

Why this ? What am I misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html)

> findContours function modifies the source image. So if you want source
>   image even after finding contours, already store it to some other
>   variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that. I understand now exactly what happened in my program